# Any simple way to get the queue length of an ActiveMQ?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

How to obtain the queue length (number of unconsumed messages sent to queue) in ActiveMQ, using Java?

Comment: You have to use JMX, since the Queue interface does not provide such information. Reference: [ActiveMQ JMX](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html), [Required MBeans](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx-support.html) Example: [managing ActiveMQ with JMX APIs](http://www.consulting-notes.com/2010/08/monitoring-and-managing-activemq-with.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to use JMX, since the Queue interface does not provide such information.

Example of retrieving the size of a specific queue:

```
// connection
String url = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi";
JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(new JMXServiceURL(url));
MBeanServerConnection connection = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
// get queue size
ObjectName nameConsumers = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost,destinationType=Queue,destinationName=myqueue");
DestinationViewMBean mbView = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(connection, nameConsumers, DestinationViewMBean.class, true);
long queueSize = mbView.getQueueSize();
```

Reference: [ActiveMQ JMX](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html), [Required MBeans](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx-support.html)

Example: [managing ActiveMQ with JMX APIs](http://www.consulting-notes.com/2010/08/monitoring-and-managing-activemq-with.html)

Comment: Thanks for hint, but I used next ObjectName: "org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Queue,Destination=queueName" and QueueViewMBean class to get queueViewMBean. Generally - approach was the same

Answer (score 3):

Like this;

```
QueueBrowser browser = session.createBrowser(queue);
Enumeration enu = browser.getEnumeration();
List list = new ArrayList();        
  while (enu.hasMoreElements()) {
    TextMessage message = (TextMessage) enu.nextElement();          
    list.add(message.getText());
   }
System.out.println("Size " + list.size());
```

Comment: NB that unless you increase maxPageSize and memoryLimit it will only browse you at most 400 messages: http://betterlogic.com/roger/2012/06/activemq-browse-all-messages

Comment: Will you read all broker messages at the consumer to simply count it, really?