# How to check if there are no message to consume in AMQ queue in stopmit node.js

Tags: node.js, stomp, amq

I am using stompit package of node.js to connect to AMQ queue to subscribe message. I used `ConnectFailover` class to create connection and `channelPool` class to create pool.

Problem I am facing is that once connection is made and if there is no message in the queue then it stay connected.

What I need a way to disconnect if there is no message to read from the queue. I don't see any option in [stompit documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stompit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that with STOMP as per [this issue](https://github.com/gdaws/node-stomp/issues/76). As a general rule, brokers like AMQ rarely allow consumers to inspect queue properties like message count.

Unless you can somehow [leverage JMX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7715037/5045563) from your node.js code, the easiest way would be to create a timer with `client.disconnect()` as a callback and wait for an amount of time suitable for your system. Whenever a message is consumed, reset the timer.